# CPT City Taxonomy in an carousel

Tags: php, owl-carousel

I want to be able to show a carousel of my taxonomy attached to my services post type, but every time I add this line of code it crashes the site

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
            'taxonomy' => 'cities',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ) );

        $args = array(  
            'post_type' => 'services',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => 8, 
            'order' => 'ASC', 
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

it seems to break on the `$terms =` line.

Cties is a Custom Post Type Taxonomy which is attached to the services CPT. All I want to do is to have my owl carousel show a list of my cities which is sorted by the ones with the highest posts attached to it if that makes sense.

I am using WordPress and the CPT UI Plugin to create the Post Type and Taxonomy

Comment: What system, framework, library are you using? Please give more detail

Comment: Don’t answer here, add more details to your question